# Does the UserDefault api guarantee privacy?

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, userdefaults

This seems like an obvious behaviour for data privacy/security, but does the ios framework ensure that the UserDefault databases that the client app and its sdks access are restricted to only the modules that created them.  So for example, if the client calls `UserDefaults.standard`, it returns a pointer to a different database than if, say, a client's sdk is calling it.

Note:  I tried looking at Apple's UserDefaults documentation but it does not make this information available.

Comment: Is it not covered under "Sandbox Considerations" in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults ?

Comment: If you are asking if your app and a framework that you add to your app get different `UserDefaults`, then the answer is no.  Frameworks/sdks that you add to your app are part of your app and can access everything your app can; your app's sandboxed files, your app's keychain entries. Location, if your app has location permission, contacts if your app has contacts permission and so on.

Comment: @Paulw11 this seems like a serious privacy breach

Comment: No.  How can you protect your app from itself? The onus is on you, as the developer, to vet the code you include in your app

Comment: if the sdk can guess a key the host app uses, it can access the value of the key.. how is that the host app's fault? Also, if the sdk happens to use the same key name it will have a naming clash.

Comment: UserDefaults has never been meant to be used for any sensitive data. It’s meant to store trivial little values like preferences. That’s it.

Comment: It would be better if you reframed your question with what you are trying to do and then ask what the proper solution is for that task.

Comment: The SDK doesn't even need to "guess" the key. It can simply dump the full contents of user defaults. But, as HangarRash says, why would there be sensitive data in UserDefaults and why would the SDK be trying to access the contents of user defaults anyway? I am not saying that anything is the host app's "fault". But you as the developer need to consider which frameworks you include and whether they are trustworthy

Comment: @HangerRash that's hardly an excuse for apple to allow data to be shared across third parties.. not devs fault if theirs docs are not raising red flags.. not to mention even just making this possible in first place. Thanks i can try to reframe the question, if i figure out how to do that easily.